# Can't Change xp Default mailto handler

Tags: windows-xp, email, thunderbird, gmail, mailto

I installed Thunderbird to try it out then uninstalled it from a windows xp machine and now when I try to change the default mailto handler from internet options programs tab, It allows me to change it to "`GMail`" but the handler doesn't actually change.

I tried using the chrome browser to change the mailto handler to a gmail client but when I click on the mail client in the drop-down list it won't change it defaults back to "`(None)`"

I have tried the `javascript:navigate()` "fix" to no avail.

How can I permanently change xp's Default mailto application?

Comment: I would just use a restoration point that was created before the installation was done automatically.

Comment: I remember i had this problem too on XP. It was too much work, but i know i add on for chrome which will change the mailto handler for chrome if you are interested

Comment: @Devid, While I will keep that in mind for future reference, I am really looking for solution to fix the OS handler options.

Comment: @Ramhound, If that's the only solution so be it but is there any explanation of whats wrong? incorrect registry keys?

Comment: @Archangel33 - If I were to hazard a guess, its simply user error, because in my experience setting the default application simply works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as how nobody left an answer I chose to go with @Ramhound's suggestion of a restore point. While this worked for me I am still very curious as to what Thunderbird(if it was truly the culprit) did to irreversibly set it self as the default mailto handler.